# Struts2 Setting a List Variable

Tags: struts2, set, ognl

I have a list at Struts2 and I want to define a variable for it. I did that:

```
<s:set name="userList" value="retrieveUserList(@com.company.project.commons.beans.Profile@YOURSELF.typeId)"/>
```

I want to get the elements of it, for example:

```
<s:property value="retrieveUserList(@com.company.project.commons.beans.Profile@YOURSELF.typeId)[5].name"/>
```

was working but after I set, it I want to use that variable bu this doesn't work:

```
<s:property value="#userList[5].name"/>
```

How to use it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be like that:

```
<s:property value="%{#userList[5].name}"/>
```